# Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-sass

I'm following Hartl's tutorial (up to chapter 5 at this point - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-signup_button) and I feel as though I have followed his instructions but I keep getting this error message when I try and view my sample_app homepage online: `Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#contact` followed by `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.` I have just added the bootstrap-sass gem to my Gemfile, have created the file app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss and added Bootstrap CSS to that file (`@import "bootstrap";`). I've looked at a few similar threads searching for a solution and have tried a few options but nothing has worked. Any thoughts? Help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you run `$ bundle install` to install the `bootstrap-sass` gem after adding it to your gemfile?

Comment: Yep, done it a couple of times now

Answer (score 1):

Pjumble, the point is you don't have to copy exactly what is shown in listings 5.6 and 5.7.

The three dots at the beggining mean you have to keep the previous contents of the file while adding the lines that follow.

So you start up with listing 5.5, then add some lines from listing 5.6, then add the rest of the lines from 5.7.